# Lenovo Thinkpad X1 Carbon - Fan keeps running after I power off & gets very hot

Tags: 20.04, suspend, power-management, lenovo, thinkpad

I have a Lenovo X1 Carbon 2021, with OS Ubuntu 20.04. During the working time it works fine and without problems.

After I power off, the screen goes dark and the fans keep working at high speed.

After 2 minutes the laptop keeps getting hot until the point you can not even barely touch it.

If I press and hold the power off button, then the laptop powers off correctly and the fun stops.

This problem occurs only when I power off. If I restart, suspend or log off it works fine.